# Javascript join/split functions not working in MS Edge

Tags: javascript, join, split, microsoft-edge

This one is odd. I have a text area whose content is altered by selecting items in a list using a  checkbox for selection.  If I uncheck the checkbox then that item needs to be removed from the list.
So, I have a textarea on my form called: buildarea (it's id)

The javascript I use is:

```
function SelectSection(form, id, checked)
```

//populates and depopulates textarea in right hand side section with selected variables

```
if (checked) {

  var checker = id.substr(5,100)
  $('#buildarea').append(checker);
  $('#buildarea').append("\r\n");
} else {

  var text = id.substr(5,100);
  var lines = $('#buildarea').val().split('\n');
  lines = lines.filter(function(val) {
    if (val.match(text)) return false
    else return true
  })
  $('#buildarea').text(lines.join('\n')).html();
```

}

the var checker just strips out some unwanted text at the start of the selected item - so don't worry about that.
OK, so the point of this is that this js works perfectly well on Chrome, Firefox AND IE (11)… but does not work in Microsoft Edge.
A list of variables might be something like:

60637;hc_j18

59157;hc_b11_1

59162;hc_b11_2

59172;hc_b11_4

59027;hc_o0k

and if deselect, let's say the 3rd item (ending in _2) then in the 3 mentioned browsers I get:

60637;hc_j18

59157;hc_b11_1

59172;hc_b11_4

59027;hc_o0k

Which is perfect.  BUT in MS Edge I get:

60637;hc_j18

59157;hc_b11_1

59172;hc_b11_4

59027;hc_

So, although the third item has been removed, the last item has had it's name cropped after the _ (underscore).
My javascript skills are not brilliant, but I wonder whether anyone else has seen behaviour like this, and how it might be overcome?

Many thanks

Paul

Answer (score 0):

You could set some debuggers in the SelectSection function and use F12 developer tools to debug your code and check the value(such as:checker and lines).

According to your description, I create a sample using the following code, it works well on my side(in IE 11, Edge and Chrome browsers), please refer to it.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function (index, item) {
                $(item).click(function () {
                    var data = [];
                    //get the checked checkbox and get the value.
                    $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function (index, item) {
                       data.push($(item).val());
                    })
                    $('#buildarea').text(data.join('\n')).html();
                });
            });
            $("#btnremoveitem").click(function () {
                var text = "59162;hc_b11_2";
                var lines = $('#buildarea').val().split('\n');
                lines = lines.filter(function (val) {
                    if (val.match(text)) return false
                    else return true
                })
                //get the specific checkbox and set the checked property.
                $("input[type='checkbox']:checked[value='59162;hc_b11_2']").prop('checked', false);

                $('#buildarea').text(lines.join('\n')).html();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" value="60637;hc_j18" />60637;hc_j18 <br />
    <input id="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" value="59157;hc_b11_1" />59157;hc_b11_1<br />
    <input id="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" value="59162;hc_b11_2" />59162;hc_b11_2<br />
    <input id="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" value="59172;hc_b11_4" />59172;hc_b11_4<br />
    <input id="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" value="59027;hc_o0k" />59027;hc_o0k<br />
    <textarea id="buildarea" rows="10" cols="20"></textarea>
    <input id="btnremoveitem" type="button" value="Remove Item" />
</body>
```

The output as below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this Dillion.  I will look at this as you are right, it seems to be working.  Clearly, there are differences between your example and mine - I will use F12 and try to track what is happening.. if I crack my problem, I will add comments below.